# How to add search refiner webpart in master page

Tags: 2013, search, refiner

I have created a custom search page and added search refiner webpart in it.

I want to to get a refiner webpart under the current navigation.

I tried it with css but as new items add in current navigation, it overlaps the refiner webpart.

Is there any way I can add this web part in the custom masterpage?

Comment: Please elaborate your question so that it is more clear.

Comment: You can use snippet gallery to copy paste Search refiener web part snippet in your master page.

Comment: I have tried to put webpartzone snippet in masterpage but got error: Master pages cannot contain WebPartZones. Any other idea?